# Yii yii-cal adding custom event from different controller gives a time that's 7 hours off

Tags: events, yii, calendar

Adding a custom event to the yii-cal calendar from a different controller displays a time on the calendar that is 7 hours off every time. Is this some kind of timezone issue? The time and date has to be formatted to strtotime in order to work on the calendar.

```
//format the date and time to use on event calendar
$model->datetime = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate);

//event record generated. Will show on calendar
$event->start = strtotime($model->datetime);
$event->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your server located / what is its time zone? If it isn't UTC, that could be where your problem is coming from.

Comment: I can get the default time zone to my time zone, now it's adding the correct time